# Building libtensorflowlite.so without any error, but share file is close to empty (KB)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

When building a libtensorflowlite.so followed by the official [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_arm64)
, but the built share file is empty even bazel build without error shown.

Answer (score 0):

After some tests, I found the problem is bazel version is not correct.
Even following the official web recommend installing the bazel and tensorflow, shown as following

[image]

So the solution is that **trying a different and new versions of bazel** to build the shared file.

To install bazel file download bazel--installer-linux-x86_64.sh from [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases), then

```
chmod +x bazel-<version>-installer-linux-x86_64.sh
./bazel-<version>-installer-linux-x86_64.sh --user
```